# How to have a collection of objects that the objects are unique based on a special field?

Tags: c#

I'm new in c#. I want to have a collection that at the first step it is empty. and each object can add to this collection in the way that it becomes unique by a value of a field. For example I want to add a new object to this collection it checks if we have an object with the value of the field "Name" of this object, don't create and add a new object and return this object, otherwise create a new object by the value of the field of "Name", add it to the collection and return it.
if there is an object with the same name:
return it
else:
create a new object add it to the collection and return it.

Comment: Override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) or implement `IEquatable<YourTeamClass>`. Then you have many ways to ensure that the name is unqiue, one is to use a `HashSet<YourTeamClass>`. You can also instead  implement a `TeamNameComparer:IEqualityComparer<YourTeamClass>` which you can use in the `Hashset<T>` constructor or with many LINQ methods like `Distinct`.

Comment: A `Dictionary<string, Team>` where the key is the team name? It all depends on what exactly you want to do with the collection, how you want to store or look up data, what you mean by "have an object [...] not add again".

Comment: The crazy man who had my question duplicate didn't understand my purpose. I don't want to find unique members of a list. I want to have something that prevents me of adding a duplicate object based on the name property. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @HimBromBeere I interpret this question as _"Which collection type to use to store unique items"_, not _"Having a collection, how to obtain only the unique items"_.

Comment: @Hossein _"The crazy man who had my question duplicate didn't understand my purpose"_ - they're not crazy, you're not being clear in what exactly you want and how you'll use it. [Edit] your question to clarify, preferably with some code that illustrates the desired usage.

Comment: I agree the dupe doesn´t match perfectly. However it should give you many ideas on how to go further. As Tim already mentioned, there are plenty of similar questions, just *search* and *try something*. Without any code that show what **exactly** you want to achieve and where you´re stuck, we can´t do much more then giving you non perfect dupes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let me visualise your example:

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
)
```

And now you have some collection of teams:

```
private List<Team> _teams = new List<Team>();

public Team AddAndGetTeam(Team team)
{
    // Try get the team and if it is found, return found object.
    // If not, add the team passed to method and return it.
    var t = _teams.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == team.Name);
    if(t == null)
    {
        _teams.Add(team);
        return team;
    }
    else
        return t;
}
```

I used `SingleOrDefault` LINQ method, which will help keep teams unique.

You can use any other method/way of getting the team with specified name.